# Making an Euclidean Distance Matrix with Random Points in Python

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, matrix, euclidean-distance

I wrote a code that produces the desired number of points in a certain width and length range in the coordinate system. How can I calculate and tabulate the distance matrix of these points I produced using the Euclidean method?

```
import random

npoints = int(input("Type the npoints:"))
width = float(input("Enter the Width you want:"))
height = float(input("Enter the Height you want:"))

sample = []
for _ in range(npoints):
    sample.append((width * random.random(), height * random.random()))
print(*[f"({w:.2f}, {h:.2f})" for w, h in sample], sep=', ')
```

Output is:

```
Type the npoints:4
Enter the Width you want:10
Enter the Height you want:10
(8.52, 3.73), (9.69, 6.87), (8.20, 6.14), (4.18, 0.76)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

How can I create a distance matrix with rondom points like this example:

[image: Distance Matrix Example]

[image: Euclidean Distance formula]

Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: you can use `itertools.combinations(list_of_points, 2)` for a pairwise grouping and apply to each pair the euclidean distance. With `numpy` can be done more smoothly due to elementwise operations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use external modules, `scipy` is very efficient for matrix calculations.

```sh
import random
import pandas as pd
from scipy.spatial import distance

npoints = int(input("Type the npoints:"))
width = float(input("Enter the Width you want:"))
height = float(input("Enter the Height you want:"))

sample = []
for _ in range(npoints):
    sample.append((width * random.random(), height * random.random()))
print(*[f"({w:.2f}, {h:.2f})" for w, h in sample], sep=', ')

#Create a matrix from these points
mat_dist = distance.cdist(sample, sample, 'euclidean')
df_mat_dist = pd.DataFrame(mat_dist)
print(df_mat_dist)
```

##### Output

```sh
Type the npoints:4
Enter the Width you want:10
Enter the Height you want:10
(8.89, 8.85), (9.00, 9.43), (9.67, 9.45), (3.96, 5.68)
          0         1         2         3
0  0.000000  0.584322  0.985072  5.856736
1  0.584322  0.000000  0.669935  6.277323
2  0.985072  0.669935  0.000000  6.839240
3  5.856736  6.277323  6.839240  0.000000
```

Comment: Thank you mate. The output of this solution looks complicated. I wonder if it is possible to get the output like the image I added to the question by starting from 0 and numbering each point?

Comment: Yes, you can transform the Numpy array (`mat_dist`) to a Pandas DataFrame (`df_mat_dist`). I edited my answer ;).

Comment: Thanks bro. You do this job like a King :)

Comment: My pleasure! :)

Comment: Hey bro is it possible for you to take a look at this question? I've been working on it for hours but couldn't come to a conclusion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70152488/finding-the-shortest-path-between-certain-points-in-the-coordinate-system-in-pyt?noredirect=1#comment124010031_70152488